# Which is the most efficient way of connecting dual monitors to a laptop (with HDMI and type C ports)?

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, usb-3.1-type-c

My laptop is Asus Vivobook S150. It has a USB 3.1 type C port and a HDMI port. I want to have a dual monitor setup with it. I assume that I should connect one of the monitors to the HDMI port.

Which kind of adapter should I choose for connecting the other monitor to type C port? (HDMI or DVI or VGA)

Would the monitor connected directly to HDMI port give better picture quality compared to the one connect to type C via an adapter?

Will the monitor connected to the type C port using adapter be able to use the graphics card or just the CPU?

Comment: you ask multiple, seemingly unrelated question and don't share so much of your desired usage. Why not just try and use it?

Answer (score 1):

DVI is same as HDMI but without the audio, so no good.

VGA is limited in resolution and frame-rate, so no good for high-end monitors.

Connecting to the port of your video card is *much preferable* to using a USB adapter with
a built-in mini display adapter such as [these](https://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&DEPA=0&Order=BESTMATCH&Description=usb+to+hdmi&ignorear=0&N=-1&isNodeId=1).

Comment: Monitor doesn't have typeC port. I do not need the audio on the monitor. So I think USB C to HDMI or DVI both would give same quality (and lower than the native HDMI to which the first monitor will be connected to). Am I right? Thank you :)

Comment: The question is, in fact, interesting and still actual to many readers. Can you, please, post your final experiences, if you still remeber them,

Comment: @meolic: Please ask the poster as a comment below his post. Remember that this dates from 2018.